# How to change ethernet local area network name in dlink n300?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, lan

I am using `D-LINK VDSL2 N300` Wireless Router. My desk top OS is `Win7`.

I personlised Wireless LAN SSID to `AVA LAN`.

I connected my desktop in LAN port 1.

I expected to show LAN Name as `AVA LAN`  in `Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections\Local Area Connection` but it shows some default/preconfigured LAN name `Abcdef`.

Please guide me in customising ethernet LAN Name configuration on the router!

Comment: LAN connections don't have that kind of capability. If you're on a private LAN (not company) you will have to manually adjust that information. For a company network it could be done using the GPO. An interesting technical read in that regard [Network Location Awareness (NLA) and how it relates to Windows Firewall Profiles](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2010/09/08/network-location-awareness-nla-and-how-it-relates-to-windows-firewall-profiles/)

Answer (score 2):

Open,

```
Network and Sharing Center
```

Then,

```
View your active networks
```

Click on Icon to go to `Set Network Properties` Window.

Comment: Yes! It can be changed on Win7! It is observed local are network name is assigned as soon as cable is plugged in to the router lan port! I hope it picks the value from some router configuration! I am interested in setting the parameter at router but not at the other side!

Comment: On further thought Ok, so it may be possible.. you have to run a script on the windows machine and make changes to registry.

Comment: Probably missed to read the last line/word of the question! LAN name is picked up automatically! I am interested in what is being used for and how to customise it on router!